# Jquery auto complete recommendation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying JQuery auto complete example. Please see - http://jsfiddle.net/LCv8L/797/

When I type "Ar" it should give "Ar" related item first. But it shows "An" first though I have given `minLength` 1. May be it is considering alphabetical order. Is there any suggestion to solve this issue?

```
    minLength: 1,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#customer-search").val(ui.item.label);
        $("#selected-customer").val(ui.item.label);
    },
    focus: function(event, ui) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#customer-search").val(ui.item.label);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

By default Autocomplete search items that contain string, not starts with.

```
$('#customer-search').autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        var filtered = $.map(data, function(item) {
            if(item.value.toLowerCase().startsWith(request.term.toLowerCase())) {
                return item;
            }
            else {
                return null;
            }
        });
        response(filtered);
    }
});
```

Comment: startsWith won't support some browsers

Comment: This does not apply to the subject matter. It's easy to check and replace with something like `this.indexOf(needle) == 0`.

Comment: Yes. its better provide a good solution as u said or else item.match !== null :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the Regular expression in namespace in the "search" method.

Please find answer in jsfiddle.net/LCv8L/800/

Comment: Thanks, I could not understand the change, could you please elaborate

Comment: As I said we can manually make the search query and return the source response by using regular expressions . Here they bound a method for the source instead of JSON array and returning the source everytime by filtering with the regexp matching the given input

Answer (score 1):

Run this code in your jsfiddle
it is working as you want.. :)
 //use regular expression is better way to prevent this.

```
   var wordlist= [
       "Afghanistan",
        "Albania",
        "Algeria",
        "American Samoa",
       "Andorra",
        "Angola",
        "Anguilla",
        "Antarctica",
        "Antigua and Barbuda",
        "Argentina",
        "Armenia",
        "Aruba",
        "Australia",
        "Austria",
        "Azerbaijan"
    ] ; 

    $("#customer-search").autocomplete({

        source: function(req, responseFn) {
            var re = $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(req.term);
            var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + re, "i" );
            var a = $.grep( wordlist, function(item,index){
                return matcher.test(item);
            });
            responseFn( a );
        }
    });
```